# Change class of div on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Seemingly simple question which is confusing me... all answers seem to be for JQuery only.

I am generating a table calendar with PHP.

[image]

Each day on the calendar is a `tr > td > div` which looks like this at the moment:

```
{cal_cell_content}
    <div class="" id="event" href="" onclick="this.className=\'selected\';return getDate({day});">
        {day}
    </div>
{/cal_cell_content}
```

When a user clicks on one of the divs I want the background of that div to change its css class to 'selected'.

Then, if the user clicks another div I want that class to change to selected and the previous class to be removed so that only one div at any time can be 'selected'.

At the moment I am using `this.className='selected` which works **except multiple divs can be selected!**

How do get behaviour so that I can select a single div and highlight it, then if I decide to click another div, the previous div becomes de-selected and the new div is 'selected'?

Comment: You need to deselect all other, and then select that one. Add one class to all your divs example "day" then do `$('.day').removeClass('selected');` and then add selected to really selected div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event listener to the div class via a loop, and add another class "selected" to the div if it is clicked. Otherwise, remove the "selected" class. The "selected" class will contain your css stuff.

For instance,

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('yourClass')
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener("click", function(){

    var selectedEl = document.querySelector(".selected");
    if(selectedEl){
        selectedEl.classList.remove("selected");
    }
    this.classList.add("selected");

    }, false);;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am going to try and cobble something together...

Comment: Code example is really great, thanks, gonna try this now.

Comment: No problem. Good luck!

Comment: Brilliant solution, the code example is clear and makes sense (and most importantly works a charm!)... saved my day!

Comment: Fantastic. Pay it forward next time then ;)

Comment: Just to check something with you... I was having a problem where I would have to click twice to select a day... so I enclosed your script in `window.onload = function {}. Is that okay?

Comment: What happened when you click twice or more times on the same month?

Comment: I put your script in a function that was already triggered by an on click. So when I clicked on a div nothing would happen (but the code would run). When I clicked a div a second time then it would get selected. By making your code run once when the window loads I can now select a div instantly as the page loads

Comment: I see. Great that you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your divs have same ID, which is wrong, do it like this

```
{cal_cell_content}
    <div class="event" href="">
        {day}
    </div>
{/cal_cell_content}


$('.event').click(function(){
   $('.event').removeClass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

with javascript:

```
{cal_cell_content}
    <div class="event" href="" onclick="selectMe(this);">
        {day}
    </div>
{/cal_cell_content}

function selectMe(obj){
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("event");
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
    {
       divs[i].className = "event";
    }
    obj.className = "event selected"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! Is there a way to do something similar without jQuery? Adding and including the whole jQuery library for something so trivial seems overkill.

Comment: Ok, I added solution with javascript

Comment: Thanks for your answer Aleksandar, I had to pick the other answer though both work great!

Answer (score 1):

try this native javascript

```
document.getElementById('event').setAttribute('class', 'selected');
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but I need the other selected div to be 'deselected' when I click a new div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#event').click(function(){
   $(this).attr('class', 'selected');
});
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is best practice to include an explanation of the code provided for the community (and the original poster) to understand the answer better.  Also, did you try this code? I don't think it works all that well (seems to have one or more bugs)

Answer (score 0):

In Standard javascript:

```
document.getElementById('foo').className += ' selected'
```

or in JQuery:

```
$('#foo').addClass('selected');
```